# How to implement a service oriented architecture in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, software-design

I'm wondering which one of the following would be the correct usage / implementation in Objective-C of a service oriented design:

The first version is specific to static languages, using protocols (interfaces):

```
// 
// get the cloud service from our service provider
// 
id<CloudServices> myService = [ServiceProvider serviceWithProtocol:@protocol(CloudServices)];
```

The second version isn't using protocols, is relying on the fact that Objective-C is actually dynamic:

```
// 
// get the cloud service from our service provider
// 
CloudServices *myService = [ServiceProvider serviceWithClass:[CloudServices class]];
```

Obviously the difference is CloudServices being an interface or protocol, and we imply that the ServiceProvider can be configured to return different implementations of the CloudServices.

**So my question is which style to choose, and why ?**
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how your services work. Using classes, the ServiceProvider can simply instantiate the class if required and perform initialization on the object. Using protocols, ServiceProvider has to know which classes are available for services, which could prevent some bugs with passing the wrong class. You could also have one class implement multiple protocols and therefore be used for different calls to serviceWithProtocol:.

Short version: Using classes would be simpler, using protocols would be more flexible and possibly safer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @ughoavgfhw . I'm just wondering on the version with classes: since obj-c is a dynamic language, we really can do whatever we want in the service provider, that is - we can even return an instance that acts like the service requested. 
So flexibility probably isn't an issue since we can override isKindOfClass (and the related methods) and return whatever object we want. 

On the note of safety: what is exactly do you have in mind ?

Comment: @Moszi I just meant flexibilty is easier with protocols because you can use conformsToProtocol:. As for safety, if you use classes, someone could load something into your program which sends in a unwanted class. You would have to check for this somehow in your implementation.